# views in collections in scala

Tags: scala, view

I understand that a view is a light-weight collection and that it is lazy. I would like to understand what makes a view light weight.

Say I have a list of 1000 random numbers. I'll like to find even numbers in this list and pick only 1st 10 even numbers. I believe using a view here is better because we can avoid creating an intermediate list esp because I'll pick only 1st 10 even numbers. Initially, I thought that the the optimization is achieved because the function I'll use in the filter method will not get executed till the method force is called but this isn't correct I believe. I am struggling to understand what makes using the view better in this scenario. Or have I picked a wrong example?

```
val r = scala.util.Random

val l:List[Int] = List.tabulate(1000)(x=>r.nextInt())

//without view, I'll get an intermediate list. The function x%2==0 will be on each elemenet of l
val l1 = l.filter(x=>(x%2 == 0))

//this will give size of l2. I got size as 508 but yours could be different depending on the random numbers generated in your case
l1.size

//pick 1st 10 even numbers
val l2 = l1.take(10)

//using view. I thought that x%2==0 will not be executed right now

val lv1 = l.view.filter(x=>(x%2 == 0))
lv1: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,List[Int]] = SeqViewF(...)

lv1.size //this is same as l1 size so my assumption that x%2==0 will not be executed is wrong else lv1.size will not be same as l1.size

val lv2 = lv1.take(10).force
```

**Question 1 - if I use view, how is the processing optimised?

Question 2 - lv1 is of type SeqViewF, F is related to filter but what does it mean?

Question 3 - what do the elements of lv1 look like (l1 for example are integers)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> `lv1.size` //this is same as l1 size so my assumption that `x%2==0` will
>   not be executed is wrong else `lv1.size` will not be same as `l1.size`

Your assumption is actually correct it's just that your means of measuring the difference is faulty.

```
val l:List[Int] = List.fill(10)(util.Random.nextInt) // ten random Ints

// print every Int that gets tested in the filter
val lv1 = l.view.filter{x => println(x); x%2 == 0}  // no lines printed

lv1.size  // ten Ints sent to STDOUT
```

So, as you see, taking the `size` of your `view` also forces its completion.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's not a very fitting example. What you are doing is better done with an iterator: `list.filter(_ % 2 == 0).take(10)`. This doesn't create intermediate collections, and does not scan the list past the first 10 even elements (view wouldn't either, it's just a bit of an overcomplication for this case).

A view is a sequence of delayed operations. It has a reference to the collection, and a bunch of operations to be applied when it is forced. The way operations to be applied are recorded is rather complicated, and not really important. You guessed right - `SeqViewF` means a view of a sequence with a filter applied. If you `map` over it, you'll get a `SeqViewFM` etc.

When would this be needed?

One example is when you need to "massage" a sequence that you are passing somewhere else. Suppose, you have a function, that combines elements of a sequence you pass in somehow:

```
 def combine(s: Seq[Int]) = s.iterator.zipWithIndex.map { 
   case(x, i) if i % 2 == 0 => x
   case(x, _) => -x
 }.sum
```

Now, suppose, you have a huge stream of numbers, and you want to combine only even ones, while dropping the others. You can use your existing function for that:

val result = combine(stream.view.filter(_ % 2 == 0))

Of course, if `combine` parameter was declared as iterator to begin with, you would not need the `view` again, but that is not always possible, sometimes you just have to use some standard interface, that just wants a sequence.

Here is a fancier example, that also takes advantage of the fact that the elements are computed on access:

```
 def notifyUsers(users: Seq[User]) = users
   .iterator
   .filter(_.needsNotification)
   .foreach(_.notify)

 timer.schedule(60 seconds) { notifyUsers(userIDs.view.map(getUser)) }
```

So, I have some ids of the users that may need to be notified of some external events. I have them stored in `userIDs`. 
Every minute a task runs, that finds all users that need to be notified, and sends a notification to each of them.

Here is the trick: `notifyUsers` takes a collection of `User` as a parameter. But what we are really passing in is a view, composed of the initial set of user ids, and a `.map` operation, getting the `User` object for each of them. As a result, every time the task runs, a new `User` object will be obtained for each id (perhaps, from the database), so, if the `_needsNotification` flag gets changed, the new value is picked up.

Surely, I could change `notifyUsers` to receive the list of ids, and do `getUser` on its own instead, but that wouldn't be as neat. First, this way, it is easier to unit-test - I can just pass an a list of test objects directly in, without bothering to mock out `getUser`. And second, a generic utility like this is more useful - a `User` could be a trait, for example, that could be representing many different domain objects.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is good and helped me understand how I can use views with some real life examples. I am marking the other comment as the 'answer' as it clarified my basic doubt that the function doesn't get executed instantly when using a view. You answer, by no means, was less useful